# Programmatically determine which camera ie front or back is being used in application iphone

Tags: iphone, camera

In My application I need to determine Which camera is being used currently and toggle the camera ie back camera to front camera I  have Implemented following code from [Check which camera is currently in use in iOS Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16460705/check-which-camera-is-currently-in-use-in-ios-application)

AVCaptureDevicePosition currentCameraPosition = [[VideoInputDevice device] position];

```
    if (currentCameraPosition == AVCaptureDevicePositionBack)
    {
        currentCameraPosition = AVCaptureDevicePositionFront;
    }
    else
    {
        currentCameraPosition = AVCaptureDevicePositionBack;
    }

    AVCaptureDevice *backFacingCamera = nil;
    NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    for (AVCaptureDevice *device in devices)
    {
        if ([device position] == currentCameraPosition)
        {
            backFacingCamera = device;
        }
    }
    NSLog(backFacingCamera ? @"Yes":@"No");
```

But Getting wrong answer

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. Assign values to variables after getting result like

```
- (void)frontCamera {
NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
for (AVCaptureDevice *device in devices) {
    if ([device position] == AVCaptureDevicePositionFront) {
       //Front camera is used
    }

 }

}
```